# Powershell sshd commands different

Tags: powershell, ssh, openssh, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I have OpenSSH installed on Windows Server 2019 https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH

SSH works great except for an issue with pipe ( | ) commands in Powershell SSH. I have successfully converted some of my | commands to ; example:

```
powershell  Mount-VHD -Path D:/VMdir/tester.vhdx -PassThru | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume
```

becomes

```
powershell  Mount-VHD -Path D:/VMdir/tester.vhdx -PassThru; Get-Disk; Get-Partition; Get-Volume
```

and it works fine, but I also have:

```
powershell (Get-VM tester | select-object MemoryMaximum).memorymaximum/1mb
```

and I can't get this one to work in SSH, works fine in windows though but not via SSH. I have tried a ; and & but it doesn't work. First why would the pipe commands work inside windows but not outside windows via ssh and any idea on how I can replace the pipe in the above command to get it work through ssh? The above command displays only a number (eg. 2048) it doesn't display any other info and that's what I need only a number.

Answer (score 0):

Use "|" instead of | works perfectly.